# Regex for escaping '^' in string

Tags: sql, regex, regex-lookarounds, apache-phoenix

I have a problem with escaping from special characters.

I am using Phoenix SQL with function `REGEXP_SUBSTR`
with parameters (`stringTerm`, `patternString`, `startInt`)

Here is my problem:

| Case | Original String | String that I want to get |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `20000000001^11111111^15817001969^1` | `11111111` |
| 2 | `20000000001^11111111^15817001969^1` | `15817001969` |

This is so far that i can get,

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('20000000001^11111111^15817001969^1','(\^|$)\w+')
```

But the output looks so bad:

```
output: ^11111111
```

Can anyone help me to solve the problems above and help me with the queries?

Many thanks to all of you!

Comment: What is your _version_ of SQL (e.g. Oracle, MySQL, Postgres, etc.) ?

Comment: You escape special characters in regexp with backslash. You may need to double it because that's also the SQL escape character.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am using Phoenix for SQL

Comment: @Barmar

As i mentioned before on my last comment, 

The queries doesnt work well, iam trying to passed the 2 '^' character, do you mean i need to double the backslash?

Comment: Put code in the question, not a comment, so you can format it readably.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is:

```
select regexp_substr(str, '[^^]+', 1, n + 1)
```

In `[^^]`, only the first `^` is "special".  The second is the character itself.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0da982cc84cec1ae771f8ebe6ad6cb29) is an example in Oracle.

Comment: Looks like the `2` argument should be `table_name.case + 1`